# Makefile addprefix removes dots

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get my Makefile to prepend a directory in the current folder to a list of paths. Something akin to this:

```
FILES = path/to/first path/to/second path/to/third

PREPENDED_FILES = $(addprefix ./localdir/, $(FILES))

all: $(PREPENDED_FILES)
    echo $^
```

Ideally the output of `make all` would be:

```
./localdir/path/to/first ./localdir/path/to/second ./localdir/path/to/third
```

But for reasons unclear to me the initial `.` gets stripped so I get:

```
/localdir/path/to/first /localdir/path/to/second /localdir/path/to/third
```

For a lot of reasons to do with my actual code I unfortunately cannot use absolute paths, so substituting `./localdir` for `$(PWD)` won't work - I really need the leading `.` in the output. I also notice that wrapping it in another function (e.g. `warning`) causes the `.` to reappear...

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the leading "./" in the *output*, or in the *prerequisites*?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behaviior (GNU Make 4.2.1). Note (that has nothing to do with your problem): you should avoid useless spaces in make function calls like `addprefix`.

Comment: By the way, is the `localdir` of your example at the root of your complete hierarchy? And do you invoke `make` form `/`? If yes, what you observe is normal because `./localdir` and `/localdir` are the same and `make` somehow *normalizes* the paths of the pre-requisites.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet it's not at root dir, but since I am using GNU Make 3.81 perhaps that has something to do with it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the dot by quoting the prefix:

```
PREPENDED_FILES = $(addprefix "./localdir/", $(FILES))
```

This will print

```
./localdir/path/to/first ./localdir/path/to/second ./localdir/path/to/third
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - the output of running that is `make: *** No rule to make target '"./localdir/"path/to/first', needed by 'foo'.  Stop.` It seems the quotes are preserved.

Comment: Using GNU Make 3.81. Digging a little further, the problem seems to stem from adding `$(PREPENDED_FILES)` as a prerequisite. If I change the body of `all` to be `echo $(PREPENDED_FILES)` and omit it as a prerequisite, I get the expected output with the leading dot. I must have a knowledge gap around how variables are handled as prerequisites...

Answer (score 0):

Led here by feeling a similar pain, and prodded by your [hint above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981316/makefile-addprefix-removes-dots#comment80911256_46981454)  I surmise that the root cause of this behaviour is of implementation of one of the [Features of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Features)

```
Strip leading sequences of ‘./’ from file names, so that ./file and file are considered to be the same file.
```

And as you have discovered, the workaround for a case such as yours is to rewrite the code as:

```
FILES = path/to/first path/to/second path/to/third

PREPENDED_FILES = $(addprefix ./localdir/, $(FILES))

all: $(PREPENDED_FILES)
    echo $(PREPENDED_FILES)
```